# Center multi-lined text verticaly in a DIV

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a `<div id="outer">` which has the following css:

```
position:relative;
width:300px;
height:125px;
float:left;
background:url(../images/callto-button1.png) no-repeat #185E7D;
```

In it is **multi-lined** text. How do i center the text vertically in the outer div?

I have tried the `display:table-cell` css method but it conflicts with other elements of the page.

The size of the text is unknown.

Is there a method or a trick that would work in all browsers from IE6 and up.

Comment: display table cell won't work on internet explorer 6 anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always come back to this page when trying to vertical centering:
http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Comment: I have tried implementing a few tries. Third time lucky. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

In this method make div display table cell & vertical align:middle. But it will not work in IE7 & IE6. Here are some hacks for that.

Tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/

**Method 2:**

You can wrap outside in a div & make it position absolute add style top:50% & margin-top should be half of the height of the div.

Tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/